How do I loop through mgz files and convert them to nii files using a shell script and freesurfer?
I need to automate converting mgz files into nii files using freesurfer. I have tried  a number of different tactics, but for some reason my script wont loop through the files and they can't be read. It isn't a permission problem because I can do other commands on the files.
I have created a shell script that prompts the user for the file path for whichever folder the files are stored in. When I run it, it says "mri_convert: missing output volume name
type mri_convert -u for usage".
Here is my script with the loop:
#!/bin/bash 

#ask user for filepath - Works 
read -p "Enter filepath: " fp 

#confirm filepath - Works 
read -p "Continue? You said ${fp} (Y/N): " confirm && [[ $confirm == [yY] || $confirm == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1 

#loop through files 
for FILE in "${fp}/*" 
do 
        #seperate file extentsion and name 
        filepath=$fp$FILE 
        filename_with_ext=$(basename $filepath) 
        filename="${filename_with_ext%.*}" 
        extension="${filename_with_ext##*.}" 

        #concatinate filename with new extension         
        ni_file="${filename}.nii" 
  
        #convert to nii using now seperated file name concaqtinated with .nii 
        mri_convert ${FILE} ${ni_file} 

done 

I'd like the script to ask the user for the filepath to the folder containing all the files. Then I want to loop through that folder and with each file I want to get the individual file name with the original file extension and the file name with the nii file extension. I am trying to do this by separating the file name from its original extension and then concatenating the file name with .nii. Finally I want to call mri_convert on the file by using its original name and file extensions and then the target file name  with the nii extension.

consider enabling debug mode (set -xv to enable; set +xv to disable) and run the script again; review the debug output to insure variables are being set as expected; alternatively, just before the mri_convert call consider adding typeset -p FILE file ni_file to have bash display the contents of these variables

having said that ... your for loop variable is FILE (all caps) while inside the loop you're referencing a variable $file (all lowercase); bash is case sensitive which means 'FILE' != 'file'

Immediate problems I see: you're using FILE in the for loop, but file inside it; these are different variable names. Also, wildcards won't expand when inside quotes, so you want for file in "${fp}"/*. $file will include the path ($fp), so adding it again with filepath=$fp$file doesn't make sense (especially since you then remove it with basename). I'd recommend fixing these, running your script through shellcheck.net and fixing what it points out, then running it with debug tracing (set -x or set -xv) to see what's happening as it runs.

See How can I debug a Bash script?.

You are using test operator in wrongw way here: [[ $confirm == [yY] || $confirm == [yY][eE][sS] ]], you should use internal test -o option [[ $confrm == y -o $confirm == Y ]]
then you are trying to use regexp in wrong way with, So my final recommendation is: [[ $confirm =~ [yY][eE]?[sS]? ]]

See BashFAQ/030 (How can I rename all my *.foo files to *.bar, or ...).

You never assign a value to variable file. Hence  mi_convert gets invoked with only one argument.

@Saboteur, that's not correct: -o isn't supported at all in bash/ksh [[ ]] (the correct alternative is [[ ... || ... ]]), and it's marked obsolescent for [ ] (where the preferred alternative to [ ... -o ... ] is [ ... ] || [ ... ]).

@Saboteur, ...see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, and note the [OB XSI] markers.

@CharlesDuffy gnu bash shows that such options are works for both of [ and [[:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html

@Saboteur, right, but for [ that's relying on GNU extensions as opposed to standardized/portable functionality; that's making code more fragile / needlessly nonportable than it would be if someone ignored your advice, with no compensating advantages.

@Saboteur, ...more to the point, -o is marked obsolescent for good reasons: parsing of tests becomes ambiguous when it's used (the awful "x$foo" practice is unnecessary when people avoid everything flagged obsolescent in the test standard); the problem with -a, -o, '(' and ')' as test arguments is that test itself needs to be able to disambiguate them from data being tested, and in [ (unlike [[) there's no special parser support to let test know which arguments were provided as code vs data.

@Saboteur, ...and as for [[, the documentation you linked makes no assertions that it supports -o. See the syntax error shown in https://ideone.com/YcB23I demonstrating that, in fact/practice, it does not.

@CharlesDuffy on my digitalocean Ubuntu it works perfectly with []: $ [ a=a -a b=b ] && echo true   true

@Saboteur, yes, it's [[ where it's outright unsupported; on [ it's "only" obsolescent.

@Saboteur, also, your expression doesn't do what you think it does. It would be just as true with [ a=b -a c=d ], because what you ran is equivalent to [ -n "a=a" ] && [ -n "b=b" ]; you need spaces around the = operators for them to be comparisons.

Thanks for all the help. I ended up with this script and it's working beautifully!
#!/bin/bash 
#ask user for filepath and change directory to filepath 
read -p "Enter filepath: " fp  
cd "$fp" 

#loop through files 
for file in * 
do 
        #seperate file extentsion and name 
        filepath="${fp}${file}" 
        filename_with_ext=$(basename "$filepath") 
        filename="${filename_with_ext%.*}" 
        extension="${filename_with_ext##*.}" 

        #concatinate filename with new extension         
        ni_file="${filename}.nii" 

        #convert to nii using now seperated file name concaqtinated with .nii 
        mri_convert --in_type mgz --out_type nii "${file}" "${ni_file}" 
done 


FYI -- there's no need for cd ~ at the end of your script, because working directory is process-local: when a script you run invokes cd, that doesn't change which directory is active for the parent shell that started that script (unless you explicitly invoked the script with source, but that's something people should only do when they want side effects modifying parent process state).

More seriously, there are some bugs in this code due to lack of quoting -- filenames with spaces will misbehave because of the unquoted expansions. Use "$FILE" or "${FILE}", not $FILE or ${FILE}; cd "$fp" instead of cd $fp, etc. (And consider sticking with lower-case names for your own variables -- that prevents you from overwriting a name with special meaning by mistake; it's more than one person who's run for PATH in and then been surprised because ls or awk is no longer in a location listed in their PATH).

@CharlesDuffy Thanks! I will fix the bugs and take out the cd ~!
